# Sql Nul Values Load Incorrectly on Snowflake as 0x0 [Square]

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble to load SQL Nul in snowflake. I'm using BCP to export sql table using page code 65001 and loading to snowflake showing SQL Nul as 
[BCP export dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QejF9.png)
[Snowflake table loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmNaJ.png)

It is showing empty as 0x0 in snowflake side. Is this a coding page issue? But I keep both using UTF-8.

Is there anyone having the same issue and I don't want to change my export query since there are a huge amount of tables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have code from a "copy into" statement on the Snowflake side that you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the NULL_IF parameter of your format definition to explicitly NULL the values that are being input into the BCP export.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Comment: It seems the postgresql could not deal with the nul from sql.